# Subtracting sql queries using the same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sql query where I want to subtract 2 queries based on location:

```
select 
(select location, sum(amount) from table1
where COA_0 = 'MAR' and SNS_0 = '1'
and ACCDAT_0 between '01-04-2018' and '31-03-2019' group by location)
- (select location, (case when sum(amount) is null then '0' else (sum(amount)) end) from table1
where COA_0 = 'MAR' and SNS_0 = '-1'
and ACCDAT_0 between '01-04-2018' and '31-03-2019' group by location)
```

Comment: What data do you have? What output are you expecting? What problem are you having to get there?

Answer (score 2):

You query is (abbreviated):

```
select
    (select ...) - (select ...) ;
```

This (subtracting 2 values that come from subqueries) is allowed only if each subquery returns a single value, i.e a single column and one row (or none in which case it is taken as null). Your subqueries return multiple rows and 2 columns. Thus, you get an error.

---

I think this is close to what you want. You could use two subqueries and then join them (on location) but since the conditions are almost identical, it is simpler to use just one:

```
select location, 
       sum(case SNS_0
               when '1' then amount
               when '-1' then - amount
               else 0
           end) as sum_amount
from table1
where COA_0 = 'MAR' and SNS_0 in ('1', '-1')
  and ACCDAT_0 between '2018-04-01' and '2019-03-31'
group by location ;
```

Also please note the changes on the date literals above. The original `'01-04-2018'` and `'31-03-2019'` might not work as you expect (I assume that `ACCDAT_0` column is of `DATE` type).